# [LUA]Getting most recurring integer in a table

Tags: sorting, lua, lua-table

i need to get the most recurring `vIndex` in a lua table structured like this:

`{{id=0, vIndex = 0},{id=34, vIndex = 1},...}`

what's the best way to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loop over each element in a table and keep track on the number of occurrences in another table where each value of `vIndex` being a key. Then loop over the second table to find the element with the max value. This will be your most frequent `vIndex`.